# Filter and Interceptors not working with spring boot camel

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, servlet-filters

I am trying to use servlet filters with spring boot camel using restlet? Typically in spring boot I would just implement javax.servlet.Filter and annotate the class with @Component and the filter would be working. When I do this using spring boot camel, I can see the filter is registered and mapped but it is never called when I send a request through.

```
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse      servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
```

I can see that the filter is initialized and mapped:
DEBUG o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans - Created Filter initializer for bean 'MyFilter'

INFO  o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'MyFilter' to: [/*]

However other filters are showing but not mine:
o.s.b.c.w.OrderedFilterName - Initializing filter 
o.s.b.c.w.OrderedFilterName - Filter "filtername' configured successfully

Comment: how can you see the filter is registered? Also above code i presume not complete since it doens't have any body? Also I presume spring boot with web component too? Show us a bit more of your setup

Comment: Yes I have a print statement in dofilter() . Using camel-spring-boot-starter and yes spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: i see in your comments there are other filters too like OrderedFilterName you are defining. Are these getting called? Are these passing down the filter chain to continue to reach yours?

Comment: OrderedFilterName is just an example , other filters are being configured successfully but mine isn't showing that line. I can setup a spring boot project and the filters just work, but there appears to be an issue using servlet filters when using camel with restlet - it seems to bypass the container.

Comment: oh i see.. if you are using camel-restlet I dont think it works that way.. same reason why a brand new apache camel app with restlet component in it doesn't need a web container to run.

Comment: Do you know what the best option for getting filters or interceptors working with spring boot camel is? Would camel-jetty or camel-servlet allow this to work?